# Are there any good techniques for calculating Hausdorff measure?

Tags: measure-theory, algorithms, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-dimension

I'm aware that many techniques have been developed for the purpose of calculating Hausdorff dimension (although I'm fairly unfamiliar with them), but my question is whether or not we have any good techniques for computing Hausdorff measure, other than working straight from the limit definition which is in general very difficult.

Answer (score 4):

The socalled *centered* Hausdorff measure contains much of the same information (in particular, it gives the same fractal dimension), but is much easier to compute. For the Hausdorff measure, one optimizes among coverings by arbitrary convex sets, while for the centered Hausdorff measure one uses coverings by balls with centers in the self-similar set, so it is easier to find optimal coverings.

An efficient algorithm, worked out with many examples, is given by Marta Llorente and Manuel Morán: [An algorithm for computing the centered Hausdorff measure of self-similar sets](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3861).